# JQuery .prop(checked,true) not setting other radio buttons to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of radio buttons that I update programmatically based upon a user's selection from a different list.  This code properly finds the radio button that matches the selected item and selects it, but it doesn't deselect the previously selected radio button.

```
$('#major_groups input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value") == group_name){
            $(this).prop("checked",true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        }
});
```

All of the radio buttons in the major_groups div have the same name, so I thought selecting one would unselect the others. I got it to work by looping through the buttons again and refreshing all of them, but this seems inefficient.

Also, will `.prop("checked",true)` fire the change event?

Comment: Why not just use an else statement, and uncheck any other radio buttons that are checked -> [**BIN**](http://jsbin.com/eqihog/3/edit), and to trigger a change event, all you have to do is chain on a `.trigger('change')` to the selected radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just triggering a click event on the radio button, something like this:

```
$('#major_groups input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value") == group_name){
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue of the event not firing; however, the proper radio button still doesn't get selected. If I loop through all of the buttons after triggering the click event and refresh them, I get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your each loop will only call refresh on the radio with specific value, and will not be called on others in the same group. The actual inputs of the group will be automatically unchecked but your plugin won't recognize the ones that are deselected unless you refresh them too.

Try this:

```
var $radios=$('#major_groups input[type=radio]');
/* first check the appropriate radio*/
var $radioToUpate=$radios.filter(function(){
        return this.value=group_name;       
}).prop("checked",true);
/* then refresh all radios with same name*/
$radios.filter('[name="'+ $radioToUpate.attr('name') +'"]').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

A link to the plugin docs might be helpful to see if plugin has methods to handle the property change that might take care of the whole group